Npm Authenticate only occasionally working in Azure Devops pipeline
I have a very strange problem I cannot seem to get my head around...
We use a private registry in the Azure Artifacts to also distribute private npm packages. My Azure Pipeline is using the npmAuthenticate Task to authenticate against this feed. The feed information is placed inside a project's .npmrc file.
The feed permisssions show the project as contributor role:
User/Group: [ProjectName]\Contributor - Role: Contributor

Randomly the build fails on the npm ci step with this error message:
#17 132.8 npm ERR! code E401
#17 132.8 npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.

With diagnostic output I see errors for differing packages. Across pipeline runs however, the packages with 401 errors vary. Also not all packages are affected. Most of them can be loaded just fine.
#17 55.03 npm http fetch GET 401 https://***/***/_packaging/***/npm/registry/resolve-from/-/resolve-from-4.0.0.tgz 50860ms attempt #2 (cache skip)

What we changed recently

We upgraded fom Node 16.14.0 to 20.12.1 including npm 10.5.0

What I tried already

I placed my own token inside the project's .npmrc file.
Verified that it is failing and succeeding on the same build agent.
I tried running with the previous node version (16.14.0) where npm ci succeeds.
I tried using node 18.20 with the same outcome
I searched the web for anything known regarding Node versions 18 and 20 having problems in this regard but to no avail.
Apparently it is working with Node 18.18 but not above.

Excerpt from the pipeline and Docker files
Pipeline:
[...]
      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: .npmrc
        displayName: 'NPM Auth'

      - bash: |
          docker build -f ./deployment/ci.Dockerfile -t $(projectName):$(Build.SourceVersion) .
        displayName: 'CI build docker image'
[...]

ci.Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.12 AS builder

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y chromium && \
    wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-5.0.1.3006-linux.zip  -O ~/sonar.zip && \
    unzip ~/sonar.zip -d /opt/sonar && \
    rm ~/sonar.zip
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium PATH="/opt/sonar/sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-linux/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /build

COPY package.json /build
COPY package-lock.json /build
COPY .npmrc /build
COPY sonar.properties /build

RUN npm -d ci # <-- It fails here. Usually run without -d.

COPY . /build

RUN npm run build:ci
[...]



It appears you are running on self-hosted agent, is it correct? Do you check the network(eg: proxy?) on the agent? Please give a try with Microsoft-hosted agent.  The error 401 indicates the token is not correct, make sure you are running with same branch between different builds. Does it fail at npm -d ci command in your dockerfile? Try to remove -d in the command for a check.

Yes, the agents are self-hosted. I need to see how and what to check exactly. I did not set up the agents myself.
Yes, 401 means token expired. However, I do get a 401 not for every package but just a few during a build. I should have stated that fact clearer, sorry.
Runs on the same branch with or without the -d flag do not change anything.

I tried your task and with same Dockerfile, it's always working on my side. As your pipeline is intermittently failed when same source code and same agent used. The difference between my pipeline and yours is the two packages json content and agent, please try: 1. Try with Microsoft-hosted agent suggested before to see if it helps. 2. Check the dependencies on the two jsons, do you have packages which fetch from upstream registry? If so, check if your account has permission on the upstream. Or you can try with another simple packages(and lock) json files, check if it's stable.

I got the information that the hosted agents are not allowed to access our TFS. So I cannot test that, I guess,
Regarding the upstream registry I'm not sure. We only have our one registry that fetches from npm.
In the package-lock.json I only see the url to our private registry in the "resolved" key for any package. But using a simple package.json is something I can try.

It could help to narrow down the issue. If simple json works, which means your environment is fine. Then you can check which packages are affected in your original jsons.

I handed the issue over to our DevOps department to further check it. Hopefully I will have the time to check the packages at one point.

Thanks for the update! If possible, you can share the details if there's any progress. Or if you have any queries, please let me know, glad to help!

Ultimately the problem seems to have been fixed by MS (or another party?). The problematic branch now works without problems. Nothing was changed, apart fom removing the --maxsockets 1 from the npm ci command. Also Upgrading to Node 20.15. did not raise any other issues.

I was experiencing a similar problem with azure devops server after moving to node 18.20/npm 10.5.0. Some builds that worked without issue with earlier versions of node and npm failed partway through an npm ci with authentication errors after switching to npm 18.20 or higher.
The issue seems to be that npm 10.5 is tripping a usage limit in azure artifacts and the requests are being throttled.  You can see if this is happening by looking at the azure devops usage details, looking for the npm requests, and checking if any have a status other than zero or mention a "Circuit Breaker" error.  The error message I found was -
Circuit Breaker "BaseSqlComponent-XXX-ReadWrite" exceeded the concurrency limit of 100. In the last 10000 milliseconds, there were: 0 failure, 0 timeout, 0 short circuited, 64 concurrency rejected, and 0 limit rejected.

My short term solution is to limit the number of sockets that npm could use npm ci  --maxsockets 1 which allowed the command to complete without errors.

Thanks Matthew! That seems to have solved my issue as well. I was running 9 builds  without any issue with that option set. Question is, if there will be an actual solution to this problem....

Ultimately the problem seems to have been fixed by MS (or another party?). The problematic branch now works without problems. Nothing was changed, apart fom removing the --maxsockets 1 from the npm ci command. Also Upgrading to Node 20.15. did not raise any other issues.

I tried your task and with same Dockerfile, it's always working on my side. As your pipeline is intermittently failed when same source code and same agent used. The difference between my pipeline and yours is the two packages json content and agent, please:

Try with Microsoft-hosted agent suggested before to see if it helps.
Check the dependencies on the two jsons, do you have packages which fetch from upstream registry? If so, check if your account has permission on the upstream. Or you can try with another simple packages(and lock) json files, check if it's stable.

